# How can I make this version of Bucket Sort using recursion?

Tags: c, sorting, radix-sort, bucket-sort

Currently what this function is doing is sorting an array using BucketSort. The array is going to be with numbers between 0 and 999. However instead of that I want to split every bucket into 10 other buckets until i am left with single digits, so basically 3 times. However I struggle to cycle through every bucket. Does anybody have any idea how to do this?

```c
void bucketSort(int arr[], int size, int divider)
{
    int max, bucket = 10, i, j, k;
    int B[bucket][size];
    int B_size[10];
    max = getMax(arr, size);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        B_size[i] = 0;
    }
    //insert element in buckets
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        j = floor( arr[i] / divider );
        B[j][B_size[j]] = arr[i];
        B_size[j]++;
    }

    //sort elements in buckets
    for(i = 0; i < bucket; i++)
    {
        quickSort(B[i], 0, B_size[i] - 1);
    }
    //bring elements back
    k = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < bucket; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < B_size[i]; j++)
        {
            arr[k++] = B[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: If you are going to call quicksort anyway why not use that to sort the whole thing?

Comment: I use quicksort here but don't want to do so. Here's how I basically wanted it to happen:
- Array: [5, 23, 45, 43, 10, 22, 55, 155, 125]
- After first call: [005]; [023, 045, 043, 010, 022, 055]; [155, 125]

- After second call: [005]; [ [010]; [023, 022]; [045, 043]; [055] ]; [ [125], [155] ]

- After third call: [005]; [ [010], [ [022], [023] ], [ [043], [045] ], [055] ], [ [125], [155] ]

Comment: What you describe sounds more like a (base-10) radix sort than a bucket sort.  The main difference would be that radix sort would normally do however many passes are needed over the whole array.

Comment: Both bucket sort and radix sort usually start by performing a scan to determine the needed size of each bucket, and then converting that into a set of bucket offsets within a single flat array.  Relative to your approach, that would reduce the amount of auxiliary space needed by a factor of 10.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for the help. The thing that I can not figure out is how to cycle through all the buckets. Like how to know which ones are already done and there is no need to cycle through them again?

Comment: @nickolay, under what circumstances do you think a bucket would not need to be processed further?  If it contains fewer than two elements, is the one that seems apparent to me, and you have that information already.  Are there any other circumstances you see?

Comment: Yes, there should only be one element in the bucket, but after that how do I move on to the next one? That's the part I can not understand. Because every way I try it leads me back to the first one